# How to remove location in the background

Tags: google-play, location

I received mail from Google about a rejection. The rejection was about removing the `access location in the background`. I also tried to remove and tried [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150#How%20to%20remove%20location%20in%20the%20background) way. But I could not find the `Sensitive app permissions` section. You can see the screen which I got

**App content section:**
THERE IS NO ANY  `Sensitive app permissions`.

[image]

ANYWAY, GO ON...

**Actioned section:**

[image]

you can see there is a `Location Permissions` section

Let us take a look...

**Location Permissions section:**
[image]
[image]

There is no section named `Sensitive app permissions`. Now, How can I remove the `access location in the background`.

Thank you